# Gradle Daemon appears to start multiple java exe

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I have upgraded to Gradle 6.8.1 and Eclipse Buildship 3 on Windows 10 64 bit. There are issues with older gradle projects. So I decide to start a new Eclipse project and copy source over to the new project. As Eclipse starts a Gradle Daemon, there is a hang. There are multiple java.exe starting in the task manager.

[image]

What on earth is going on?

The only way out is to `taskkill /IM java.exe /F`

*UPDATE*
I go to the command line and run gradle it also attempts to start large numbers of daemons without cleaning anything up. It starts with

`Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details`

[image]

*UPDATE* I've rolled back to Gradle version 6 and up came Windows Firewall to allow java.exe and the daemon works.

[image]

If I try and install 6.8.1 having Firewall access there's the same issue. If I turn off the Firewall the same problem.

It did not fix the problem though, Eclipse still starts multiple versions of java.exe when trying to create even a blank Gradle project. AAAAArgh!!

Comment: What's your Gradle preference page set to use?

Comment: It was set to the Gradle directory, and Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to resolve this was uninstall and reinstall Eclipse... without a separate Gradle instance:

[image]